# Draw a "grid" between arranged plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm working with 4 different plots and I'm using ggarrange() from the ggpubr-package to put them in a single plot. I've prepared an example:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 1")
p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 2")
p3 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 3")
p4 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 4") +
  facet_wrap(~Species)

plot.list <- list(p1, p2, p3, p4)

ggarrange(plotlist = plot.list)
```

Output: 
[image]

I would like to draw a border around the single plots, like so:

[image]

Is there any way to draw this border? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grid.polygon()` is quite manual but I think it can do the trick:

**Using RStudio**

```
library("ggpubr")
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 1")
p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 2")
p3 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 3")
p4 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 4") +
  facet_wrap(~Species)

plot.list <- list(p1, p2, p3, p4)

ggarrange(plotlist = plot.list)
x = c(0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
y = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5,0, 0.5, 1)
id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
grid.polygon(x,y,id)
```

[image]
**Using Shiny (Edit)**

When doing it within a shiny-app, ones needs to add the grid using `annotation_custom()`, as follows:

```
    ggarrange(plotlist = plot.list) + 
    annotation_custom(
             grid.polygon(c(0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
                          c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5,0, 0.5, 1), 
                          id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), 
                          gp = gpar(lwd = 1.5)))
```

Comment: Just a quick addition, because I'm using this plot within a shiny-app I had to add the grid using `annotation_custom()`, like so: `ggarrange(plotlist =  plot.list) +
  annotation_custom(grid.polygon(c(0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
               c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5,0, 0.5, 1),
               id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
               gp = gpar(lwd = 1.5)))`

Comment: @brettljausn, I added your point in the explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this will work for you, but you can just put borders around your individual plots. However, this includes borders on the outside of the layout. Your description seems like you're not opposed to that, but there are only inner gridlines in your example plot.

You could add the `theme` call when you create the plots; rather than editing the plot creation, I just did it to each plot in the list before sticking them all together.

```r
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

#### same plot creation here ######

plot.list <- lapply(list(p1, p2, p3, p4), 
                    function(p) p + theme(plot.background = element_rect(color = "black")))

ggarrange(plotlist = plot.list)
```

[image]

Comment: I think the answer given by Carles above best answers what the OP asked for!